# After renaming my signal in C++ I get QML error

Tags: qt, qml, signals-slots

After renaming my signal from "testSignal" to "DevFound" in C++ I get QML error:

```
Cannot assign to non-existent property "onDevFound" onDevFound: console.log(device)
```

I have tried to clean, rebuild, delete build files and restart Qt Creator.

Comment: What have you changed and what was written before?

Comment: @Kakadu: Is was testSignal and I renamed it to DevFound. I just figured out the problem, signal name needs to start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed my C++ signal name from "testSignal" to "DevFound". The problem was the the signal name needs to start with a lower case letter so new name is "devFound".

Comment: Are you sure? The documentation does not say anything like that, only for properties.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I am sure that this was the only thing I modified. I tried doing it back again to some other name with upper case first letter and it did not work. Maybe it is because QML receives the signal as a property in the background?